# Can i install a 64bit lubuntu on my i386 pc?

Tags: lubuntu, laptop, intel, 32-bit

My laptop is not support x86_64. Can i install 64bit lubuntu on it?

CPU:Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270   @ 1.60GHz

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot.

I have an old eeepc from 2007, with recorded (*by me*) specs as

asus eepc 1000HE (intel atom n270, 1gb, intel mobile 945gse integrated)

The latest Lubuntu I believe it would install is Lubuntu 18.04 LTS from 2018-April, and is supported until 2021-April.

I stopped using it for testing, as it's BIOS wouldn't allow me to boot USB thumb-drives, which is why the hesitation (ie. what I believe it would install) as i stopped creating DVD-RW test media.

Comment: FYI: I am using Lubuntu 18.04 LTS on pentium m (x86 only) laptops, and did continue testing later releases (eg. 18.10 & 19.04) on pentium m laptops that I could boot thumb-drives on, but with both 18.10 & 19.04 being *end-of-life*, the best option now is a 18.04 LTS flavor, or *off-topic* debian.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot.

64-bit hardware is required for a 64-bit Operating System.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is what architecture is defined for. To run a 64-bit operating system, you need hardware that can `address` 64-bit address your OS is using which in case a 32-bit processor does not support.

Comment: A x86 cpu with PAE (i686) can address 64-bit memory addresses too. PAE or physical address extension is different to the op-codes or cpu architecture (or the 'lm' or long_bit flag) which defines amd64 or 64-bit. Your wording implies to me seems to mix this up.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your laptop doesn't support a 64 bit OS.

Additionally, Lubuntu developers stated that 32-bit x86 releases will no longer be offered, while Lubuntu 18.04 LTS will continue to be supported.

[Lubuntu Will Stop Providing 32-Bit Releases](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Lubuntu-No-More-32-Bit)

That said, the newsest Lubuntu version you can run is 18.04 LTS.

Good luck!!